# Centering element doesn't work with margin: 0 auto;

Tags: css

Elements doesn't align to centre when margin: 0 auto; applied.
See the code here.  https://jsfiddle.net/helloworld123/vhhx1o7n/

I have to align the elements in centre of page(.entry-wrap should be aligned to centre of the page) and its children(.entry) should be floated to left.

I have this working to some extent in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/helloworld123/n8o18ges/ ,but I don't want the elements in third row to be aligned to center.

```
<div class="entry-wrap">
    <div class="entry">
        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/43342/screenshots/2772190/dribbble_2016_partb_001_teaser.jpg" alt="Shot title" />
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/43342/screenshots/2772190/dribbble_2016_partb_001_teaser.jpg" alt="Shot title" />
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/43342/screenshots/2772190/dribbble_2016_partb_001_teaser.jpg" alt="Shot title" />
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/43342/screenshots/2772190/dribbble_2016_partb_001_teaser.jpg" alt="Shot title" />
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/43342/screenshots/2772190/dribbble_2016_partb_001_teaser.jpg" alt="Shot title" />
    </div>
</div>

body {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.entry-wrap {
    width: 500px;
  height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
.entry {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

This is what I want to achieve
[image]

Comment: I couldn't add more links or images, so adding it here.

Comment: This is what I want to achieve. http://i.imgur.com/NeiWnKK.png?1

Comment: Sorry, updated the link now.  This is the URL: https://jsfiddle.net/helloworld123/vhhx1o7n/

Comment: The elements(.entry) doesn't align to centre if I use margin: 0 auto; I have this working to some extent here https://jsfiddle.net/helloworld123/n8o18ges/ , but the <div class="entry"> to be aligned to left

Comment: You seem to be really close. Use `display: inline-block` in the first fiddle instead of `float: left`, and it works.

Comment: For `margin: 0 auto;` to center the element, you have to set the `width` also.

Comment: I tried setting width, it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

1.) On `.entry`, use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;`

2.) On `.entry-wrap` use `text-align: center;`

https://jsfiddle.net/fe6cmr07/

Comment: Not exactly the effect he wanted

Comment: The last element in .entry div aligned to centre. Not that I wanted.

Comment: you can't align the last single item to the left of the left items above, since they are not aligned left. You'd have to use an additional wrapper and center that one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all the elements inside `entry-wrap` are floated, so `entry-wrap` is collapsing, to fix it, you can add `overflow:hidden` to it, or use a [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) solution.

If you want the child elements to be centered, it's just a matter of playing with the width of the wrapping div:

```
body {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.entry-wrap {
    width: 620px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.entry {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o8aj3hqL/

Comment: Incase if modify the width to 700px in .entry-wrap, the elements doesn't align to centre.

Comment: Do you need this to be of flexible width?

Comment: Yes. The page is flexi width.

Comment: Are the images flexible as well, or do they have a fixed width?

Comment: No. The images will be of fixed size. 200px.

Comment: For fixed width, its always working. I need a solution for responsive website

Comment: Sorry for all the questions but i need to understand exactly what you need, do you always want 3 images in a row no matter the width?

Comment: No. The images can be varied based on the width. Its not always 3 images in a row. Suppose the .entry width is 200px, and page width is 1000px, 5 images(ignore margin for now) should be in row. If the page width is 800-900px, 4 images should per row. but it should be always center aligned.

Answer (score 0):

your block with `margin: 0 auto` is in the center of `<body>`. the problem is with the child elements since they are `floated` and it won't be `center aligned` unless you use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vhhx1o7n/1/

Comment: Thanks for helping. The last element in .entry is not floated to left.

Comment: to make that happen, you can use `text-align-last: left;` but it might not be cross-browser. and this is the best we can deliver with pure css

Comment: Okay. Thanks for helping. There should be a way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes. It works. But looks like you are modifying the image width(width: 33.33%). For example, look at dribbble.com, they are able to achieve this without modifying the image attributes. But the problem the same solution doesn't work here.

Comment: I don't want to modify the .entry attributes, this will affect the image resolution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. :)

Comment: are you okay if the padding is modified? http://prntscr.com/bga533 this. if so i can get you solution. if not you should use javascript

Comment: Yes. sure. The padding doesn't matter.

Comment: See the first row and second row, If I modify the width of .entry-wrap to 690px. http://prntscr.com/bgaugf

Comment: Looks like this won't be possible. Dribbble uses some other technique(fixing the parent div width to some fixed amount(varied based on the page width) and child has (margin: 0 15px 30px 15px;) which sets the elements in center.

Comment: Okay fine. Thanks a lot for helping me. 
It is possible by setting parent div width to some fixed width(varied based on page width) and setting the child div(.entry) margin to keep it aligned to center. Refer this http://prntscr.com/bgb0b7 and http://prntscr.com/bgb0ia

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
.entry-wrap {
  width: 618px;
  height: 318px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
.entry {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-wrap">
  <div class="entry">
    <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/43342/screenshots/2772190/dribbble_2016_partb_001_teaser.jpg" alt="Shot title" />
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/43342/screenshots/2772190/dribbble_2016_partb_001_teaser.jpg" alt="Shot title" />
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/43342/screenshots/2772190/dribbble_2016_partb_001_teaser.jpg" alt="Shot title" />
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/43342/screenshots/2772190/dribbble_2016_partb_001_teaser.jpg" alt="Shot title" />
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/43342/screenshots/2772190/dribbble_2016_partb_001_teaser.jpg" alt="Shot title" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing the width of .entry-wrap to 800px and see, https://jsfiddle.net/helloworld123/rfmz52k8/ , The elements in .entry are not centered.

Comment: The elements in .entry-wrap are not centered to the page. You can see lot of space on right side. The page is not aligned to centre.

Comment: Since you know the width of the images, I chose `618px` specifically because that would center it. If you change it, then of course it won't be centered.

Comment: Okay. Basically I would have lot of .entry(of 200px) in my page, based on the width of the page, number of elements in a row would be varied, For example, if the page width is 500px, two elements should be displayed in a row. If the page width is 900px, three elements should be displayed, but the elements are not aligned to centre